# MySQL поиск по двум связным таблицам

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Имеется три таблицы:

**1. a_books**

[image: a_books]

**2. a_books_authors**

[image: a_books_authors]

**3. a_authors**

[image: a_authors]

Требуется осуществить поиск по таблицам, чтобы запросом можна было найти как книгу, так и автора.

Написал следующий запрос:

```
SELECT
    a_books.book_title,
    GROUP_CONCAT(a_authors.author_name) AS author_name
FROM
    a_books
    INNER JOIN a_books_authors ON a_books.book_id = a_books_authors.book_id
    INNER JOIN a_authors ON a_books_authors.author_id = a_authors.author_id 
WHERE
    a_books.book_title LIKE '%book%' 
    OR a_authors.author_name LIKE '%book%' 
GROUP BY
    a_books.book_title
```

Который прекрасно работает если искать книгу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если вместо `LIKE '%book%'`, ввести `%author 1%`, то выведет только одного автора книги, а конкретно **Author 1**, в то же время мне нужно получить всех авторов, как в первом запросе...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я написал следующий запрос, который работает как нужно:

```
SELECT
    a_books.book_title,
    GROUP_CONCAT(a_authors.author_name) AS author_name 
FROM
    a_books
    INNER JOIN a_books_authors ON a_books.book_id = a_books_authors.book_id
    INNER JOIN a_authors ON a_books_authors.author_id = a_authors.author_id 
GROUP BY
    a_books.book_id 
HAVING
    author_name LIKE '%author 1%' 
    OR a_books.book_title LIKE '%author 1%'
```

Вопрос: Является ли данный вариант единственно возможным, и верным? И является ли он вообще верным? Насколько я знаю при использовании `HAVING`, нет возможности использовать индексы, в отличии от `WHERE LIKE 'query%'`. Есть ли аналог решения задачи? Или оставить как есть? Спасибо!

Comment: На авторов надо проверять в HAVING, уже после группировки...

Comment: @Akina, Прошу прощения немного не понял, вроде так и делаю.

Comment: *Является ли данный вариант единственно возможным* Нет. *и верным? И является ли он вообще верным?* Да.

Comment: @Akina, Хорошо спасибо. Поставлю вопрос по другому: Возможно ли оптимизировать запрос для использования индексов? Чтобы запрос не проходил по всей таблице?

Comment: Схематично: Берём 1 копию книг, связок и авторов, отбор по нужному автору, получаем книги с его участием. Берём 2 копию связок, связываем с 1-й по книге. Добавляем 2 копию авторов. Книги берём из 1 копии книг, а авторов из 2 копии авторов. Всё.

Comment: @Akina, Спасибо, подумаю над этим. Есть ли в этом смысл? Или можна оставить вариант с HAVING?

Comment: HAVING работает с данными, находящимися в памяти (если, конечно, книг не миллиард) - а поиск в памяти достаточно быстрый, даже когда выполняется сканирование.

Comment: @Akina, Ясно, благодарю!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a_books.book_title,
    GROUP_CONCAT(a_authors.author_name) AS author_name
FROM
    a_books
    INNER JOIN a_books_authors ON a_books.book_id = a_books_authors.book_id
    INNER JOIN a_authors ON a_books_authors.author_id = a_authors.author_id 
WHERE
    a_books.book_title LIKE '%book%' 
    OR a_books.id in(
      select book_id
        from a_authors a, a_books_authors b
       where a.author_name LIKE '%book%' and b.author_id=a.author_id
    )
GROUP BY
    a_books.book_title
```

Что касается использования индексов, об этом можете не волноваться, они очень редко используются при наличии в запросах OR и в принципе не могут быть использованы при использовании LIKE с маской начинающейся на `%`. Так что в этом запросе все равно будет полное сканирование таблиц книг и авторов. И оптимизировать поиск в таком случае возможно только с использованием [полнотекстового поиска](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html) и соответствующих индексов.

Comment: А можна пример с полнотекстовым индексом? Спасибо!